# Replacing two characters in a string with a specified set of characters to create all possible combinations

Tags: python

The goal is to generate all possible combinations with a string `0a1b2c3d4e5` by changing two characters.

Code I have so far:

```
import itertools

pattern_index_zero = "xa1b2c3d4e5"

a = [['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] if (c == 'x') else c for c in pattern_index_zero]
b = [''.join(lst) for lst in list(itertools.product(*a))]
for s in b:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
0a1b2c3d4e5
1a1b2c3d4e5
2a1b2c3d4e5
3a1b2c3d4e5
4a1b2c3d4e5
5a1b2c3d4e5
aa1b2c3d4e5
ba1b2c3d4e5
ca1b2c3d4e5
da1b2c3d4e5
ea1b2c3d4e5
```

It changes the first character which is okay, but the problem is that I want to change the second, third character as well, and continuing up to the last one.

The final goal is to generate all possible combinations to change **two** characters in a string, for example:

```
xx1b2c3d4e5
xaxb2c3d4e5
xa1x2c3d4e5
xa1bxc3d4e5
....
xx1b2c3d4e5
0xxb2c3d4e5
0x1x2c3d4e5
0x1bxc3d4e5
```

where `x` can be `0,1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,e`, how hard it is in terms of code to increase the number of `x` to 3 or even 4?

**EDIT** The user **Timus** has an answer. I'll do my best to explore all answers, thank you all!

Comment: Just curious: What is the motivation behind this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```py
pattern_index_zero = "xa1b2c3d4e5"
pattern = [letter for letter in pattern_index_zero]
possible_options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

indices_values = []
for i0 in range(0, len(pattern)):
    for i1 in range(0, len(pattern)):
        if i0 != i1 and (i1, i0) not in indices_values:
            indices_values.append((i0, i1))

current_indices_index = 0

possibilities = []

for index0, index1 in indices_values:
    for new_option0 in possible_options:
        if new_option0 != pattern[index0]:
            for new_option1 in possible_options:
                if new_option1 != pattern[index1]:
                    pattern_copy = pattern.copy()
                    pattern_copy[index0] = new_option0
                    pattern_copy[index1] = new_option1
                    possibilities.append(''.join(pattern_copy))
```

This is uses a basic structure of `for` loops to solve the problem. We start by creating a list for which the 2 indices whose value we will change. This list looks a bit like: `[(0, 1), (0, 2), ..., (1, 0), (1, 2), ...]` and contains all the options.

Then, we iterate through every single possible index of whose value we can change.

```py
for index0, index1 in indices_values:
```

inside this, we also iterate through all the values to which the string's index could be changed too.

```py
for new_option0 in possible_options:
```

We then check if the `new_option0` does not equal the current one to make sure we get no duplicates. If not, we iterate through the possible options again - this time for changing the 2nd index. We check that `new_option1` does not equal the current one again.

Finally, we append the edited value.

To confirm that there are indeed no duplicates, the following code outputs `True`:

```py
len(possibilities) == len(set(possibilities))
```

If you want to increase the number of indices you edit, I suppose you could just increase the number of `for` loops and `if` statements. It's a pretty moduler structure.

Comment: Thank you, it seems really close to what I'm trying to solve, i just don't get anything after python3 file.py command

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could ask another question after doing your research? Also, if you found this answer helpful, would you mind upvoting/accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try another tool from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations

s = "0a1b2c3d4e5"
positions = tuple(range(len(s)))
for i, j in combinations(positions, 2):
    print(s[:i] + s[j] + s[i+1:j] + s[i] + s[j+1:])
```

**EDIT**: Okay, another try :). Is that what you're looking for:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

s = "0a1b2c3d4e5"
r = "012345abcde"
for i, j in combinations(tuple(range(len(s))), 2):
    for r1, r2 in product(r, r):
        print(s[:i] + r1 + s[i+1:j] + r2 + s[j+1:])
```

**EDIT 2**: If you want to exclude multiples you could unify via `set()`:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

s = "0a1b2c3d4e5"
r = "012345abcde"
output = []
for i, j in combinations(tuple(range(len(s))), 2):
    for r1, r2 in product(r, r):
        output.append(s[:i] + r1 + s[i+1:j] + r2 + s[j+1:])
output = set(output)
print(output)
```

**EDIT 3**: I couldn't get your question how this is extendable to a higher number of replacements out of my mind. I hope you don't mind me adding a generalisation. It's a bit more complex. And the output volume grows fast. I therefore refrained from printing it to the console and used a file instead (with detailed output). Maybe you're interested. No problem if not, I had a lot of fun. One question: Do you need this stuff to solve some real world problem?

```
from itertools import combinations, product

# Base string
base = "0a1b2c3d4e5"
# Length of the base string
len_of_base = len(base)
# String with replacement characters
replacements = "012345abcde"
# Number of replacements
num_of_replacements = 3
output = {}
for istart, *imiddle, iend in combinations(range(len_of_base),
                                           num_of_replacements):
    for rstart, *rrest in product(replacements,
                                  repeat=num_of_replacements):
        new = base[:istart] + rstart
        for i, j, r in zip([istart] + imiddle,
                           imiddle + [iend],
                           rrest):
            new += base[i+1:j] + r
        new += base[iend+1:]
        if new not in output:
            output[new] = {}
            output[new]['positions'] = tuple([istart] + imiddle + [iend])
            output[new]['replacements'] = tuple([rstart] + rrest)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key in output:
        file.write(f"{key} - "
                   f"Positions {output[key]['positions']} "
                   f"replaced with {output[key]['replacements']}\n")
```

Output:

```
000b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '0')
001b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '1')
002b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '2')
003b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '3')
004b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '4')
005b2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', '5')
00ab2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', 'a')
00bb2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', 'b')
00cb2c3d4e5 - Positions (0, 1, 2) replaced with ('0', '0', 'c')
...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how exactly I can manage which characters I can use? Like a,b,c,0,1,2, if let's say I want to remove/add. Also I got 55 combinations which I suppose is not even close to the real number, so it doesn't compute all possible combinations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ... sorry. With respect to the 55: Without replacement there are 55 possibilities to pick 2 different elements out of a set of 11 elements (11 * 10 / 2). And the string has 11 characters. But again: Maybe I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: the goal is to find all possible combinations, assume replacement is required, that's my bad, I did upvote your effort and really enjoy seeing people trying to help, I'll explore more to find out, if you have an intention to make a solution to find all possible outcomes with an ability to choose what value "x" can be it'll definitely help, thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

You can user **itertools.combinations** to achieve this:
since you want to swap/change two characters, I am passing 2 in the argument.

```py
from itertools import combinations 
a = '0a1b2c3d4e5'
for i, j in combinations(a, 2):
    # rest of the code swaps the characters
    dummy = a.replace(i, '_')
    first_repalcement = dummy.replace(j, i)
    second_replacement= first_repalcement.replace('_', j)
    print(second_replacement)
```

**Output**
a01b2c3d4e5
1a0b2c3d4e5
ba102c3d4e5
2a1b0c3d4e5
ca1b203d4e5
3a1b2c0d4e5
da1b2c304e5
4a1b2c3d0e5
ea1b2c3d405
5a1b2c3d4e0
01ab2c3d4e5
0b1a2c3d4e5
021bac3d4e5
0c1b2a3d4e5
031b2cad4e5
0d1b2c3a4e5
041b2c3dae5
0e1b2c3d4a5
051b2c3d4ea
...

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how exactly I can manage which characters I can use? Like a,b,c,0,1,2, if let's say I want to remove/add. Also I got 55 combinations which I suppose is not even close to the real number, so it doesn't compute all possible combinations.

Comment: May be I misunderstood your questions. There are 55 combinations of  2 characters in your string, now when it comes to changing them, what are the available characters to which these two can be changed? are duplicate characters acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Here was my thought. Create all 2 combinations of the `pattern_index_zero` string and then replace them with 2-combinations of the replacement items.

I used a shorter list to easily see the result.

`s = '12345'` and `rep = 'ABCDE'`

Both strings are 5 in length and the number of combinations from each is `5 Choose 2 == 10`

So, the total arrangements are 10 * 10 == 100

```
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint

#s = "xa1b2c3d4e5"
s = '12345'

#rep = ['0','1','2','3','4','5', 'A','B','C','D','E']
rep = 'ABCDE'

L = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
        for char1,char2 in combinations(rep, 2):
            L.append(s[:i] + char1 + s[i+1:j] + char2 + s[j+1:])

print(len(L))
pprint(L)
```

This prints:

```
100
['AB345',
 'AC345',
 'AD345',
 'AE345',
 'BC345',
 'BD345',
 'BE345',
 'CD345',
 'CE345',
 'DE345',
 'A2B45',
 'A2C45',
 'A2D45',
 'A2E45',
 'B2C45',
 'B2D45',
 'B2E45',
 'C2D45',
 'C2E45',
 'D2E45',
 'A23B5',
 'A23C5',
 'A23D5',
 'A23E5',
 'B23C5',
 'B23D5',
 'B23E5',
 'C23D5',
 'C23E5',
 'D23E5',
 'A234B',
 'A234C',
 'A234D',
 'A234E',
 'B234C',
 'B234D',
 'B234E',
 'C234D',
 'C234E',
 'D234E',
 '1AB45',
 '1AC45',
 '1AD45',
 '1AE45',
 '1BC45',
 '1BD45',
 '1BE45',
 '1CD45',
 '1CE45',
 '1DE45',
 '1A3B5',
 '1A3C5',
 '1A3D5',
 '1A3E5',
 '1B3C5',
 '1B3D5',
 '1B3E5',
 '1C3D5',
 '1C3E5',
 '1D3E5',
 '1A34B',
 '1A34C',
 '1A34D',
 '1A34E',
 '1B34C',
 '1B34D',
 '1B34E',
 '1C34D',
 '1C34E',
 '1D34E',
 '12AB5',
 '12AC5',
 '12AD5',
 '12AE5',
 '12BC5',
 '12BD5',
 '12BE5',
 '12CD5',
 '12CE5',
 '12DE5',
 '12A4B',
 '12A4C',
 '12A4D',
 '12A4E',
 '12B4C',
 '12B4D',
 '12B4E',
 '12C4D',
 '12C4E',
 '12D4E',
 '123AB',
 '123AC',
 '123AD',
 '123AE',
 '123BC',
 '123BD',
 '123BE',
 '123CD',
 '123CE',
 '123DE']
>>>
```